Any counterexamples that shows failure of Fubini's theorem when the measure is not a product measure?
I'm reading Durrett's Probability: theory and examples, section 1.7(Product Measures, Fubini's Theorem). In theorem 1.7.1, he proved the existence and uniqueness of the product measure $\mu=\mu_1\times \mu_2$ on the product $\sigma-$algebra $\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{A}\times\mathcal{B}$. From my understanding, the product measure $\mu$ is only one possible measure we can define on $\mathcal{F}$, and other measures $\mu^*$ not taking the product form could also be defined on $\mathcal{F}$. Then in Theorem 1.7.2 (Fubini's theorem), he presented the result that integration with respect to the product measure can be computed as two iterated integrations. I'm wondering if there are any classic counterexamples that shows the importance of working with product measure in Fubini's theorem: that is, counterexamples that show $\int _{X\times Y}fd\mu^*$ cannot be written as two iterated integrations, where $\mu^*$ is not a product measure.
